# First and second derivative of $f(x)=\sqrt{1+x}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, proof-verification

I'm taking an introduction to calculus course. Are my calculations correct for first and second derivative of $f(x)=\sqrt{1+x}$ ? :

$$f(x)=\sqrt{1+x}$$

$$f(x) = (1+x)^{\frac{1}{2}}$$

$$\frac{df}{dx}=\frac{1}{2}(1+x)^{\frac{1}{2}-\frac{2}{2}}=\frac{1}{2}(1+x)^{-\frac{3}{2}}$$

$$\frac{d^2f}{dx^2}=\frac{3}{2}*\frac{1}{2}(1+x)^{-\frac{3}{2}-\frac{2}{2}}=\frac{3}{4}(1+x)^{-\frac{5}{2}}$$

Comment: If all you want is verification, just use a calculator. If you have a question about the *process*, then please ask it.

Comment: Check the sign for the second derivative. And specify proper intervals

Comment: In the exponent: $1/2-1=-1/2$, not $-3/2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No**, they are not. You make your *first* mistake when you write
$$
\frac{1}{2}-\frac{2}{2} = -\frac{3}{2}
$$
when computing the exponent in the first derivative. Then, of course this error cascades to the second derivative, but even then you make a *second* mistake by forgetting the minus sign:
$$
\frac{d^2 f(x)}{dx^2} = -\alpha\cdot \frac{1}{2}(1+x)^{-\alpha-1}
$$
not $\alpha\cdot \frac{1}{2}(1+x)^{-\alpha-1}$ as you wrote. (You do it with $\alpha=3/2$, but it should be $1/2$ — cf. your first mistake).

Now, to check your result, I strongly encourage use to use a formal system (calculator, for instance, or [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=derive+sqrt(1%2Bx)&t=crmtb01)). This will at least tell you if your end result is correct. *(Note that it may still be correct due to two or more errors cancelling each other...)*

Answer (score 1):

> first derivative

$$f (x)=\sqrt {x+1} \implies $$
$$f^2 (x)=x+1 \implies $$
$$2f (x)f'(x)=1 \implies$$
$$f'(x)=\frac {1}{2f (x)}=\frac {1}{2}(x+1)^{-\frac {1}{2}} $$

> second derivative

$$ 4 (f'(x))^2=(x+1)^{-1}$$
$$\implies 8f'(x)f''(x)=-(x+1)^{-1-1} $$
$$\implies f''(x)=\frac {-(x+1)^{-2}}{4 (x+1)^{-\frac {1}{2}}} $$
$$=\frac {-1}{4}(x+1)^{-\frac {3}{2}} $$

Comment: Even though this is correct and a nice solution. It might come across as magic for someone taking precalc.

Comment: @Olba12 Answers don't necessarily have to be geared towards the OP. There is another audience out there, and they like to see the magic shows.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt Simply thnks.